# Image Slider Effect that respond to mouse movement

Tags: javascript, image, animation

I'm looking for a way to implement image effect like the one seen in this website -> http://62models.com/ Is there any existing libraries or can somebody point mo to a right direction for adding this to a web page.

Answer (score 0):

In the development toolbar (Hotkey: F12) on the network tab you can see the files that are loaded when you browse at the site.

I looked through them and found [main.min.js](http://62models.com/wp-content/themes/62models/js/main.min.js) which included multiple *banners* from different javascript libraries. Looking them up I think the page uses [PixiJS](http://www.pixijs.com/) and [StackBoxBlur](http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html). (Not sure if [imagesLoaded](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/) is used.)

FYI: It is always a nice try to load the unminified source, but in this case 
[main.js](http://62models.com/wp-content/themes/62models/js/main.js) doesn't help much.

*(My 2 cents: The effect looks nice, but is worthless on touchscreens and is not implemented well for smaller screen width.)*

Comment: Yeah, inspecting main.js or main.min.js doesn't help much, I've already red it and see if I can see any hints.

Comment: Since there isn't a finished framework or library for what you want to do, you will have to code it on your own. (You might use the same frameworks/libraries though.) Maybe you can come up with something responsive!